# How to create connection on informatica for hive?

Tags: hive, informatica

My hive database version is 1.1.0. I am using informatica devoleper. I am opening "New Developer Connection" choosing type for JDBC.
[image: informatica connection settings] is like that. When I try to `test connection` The answer is `Method not supported`. How can I connect to database on informatica devoleper?

Comment: I added jars to "C:\Informatica\9.6.1\clients\externaljdbcjars"

Answer (score 0):

You can use odbc for hive. This can be done from Apache/Cloudera whatever is your provider.
Download the driver from https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/odbc/2-5-12.html
Then Install/configure data using your details.